# How can I prevent a WebBrowser Control from automatically switching to Bing search?

Tags: c#, windows-phone

My windows phone app has a web browser control in it and it defaults to bing.com and allows users to search Bing. However, whenever I try searching, it automatically suspends my app and switches over to the Bing search app on the phone. In fact, whenever I visited Bing in the web browser control, it would just immediately switch to the Bing app, I had to change the user agent of the web browser control to prevent it from switching, but that only applies to a single website and as soon as a switch is performed, it will switch back to the original settings and cause bing.com to bring up the bing app again.

Is there any way around this or any to prevent the browser from automatically switching to the bing app? Or perhaps is there a way to permanently change the web browser control's user agent to something that won't cause the automatic switch?

Comment: There's other search engines besides Bing? What an amazing concept...

Comment: For the purpose of this app, I need to use Bing for a very specific purpose.